# difference between IEnumerable<T>.Reverse & List<T>.Reverse

Tags: c#, generic-collections

Why `IEnumerable<T>.Reverse()` returns the reversed collection with the original collection and `List<T>` reverses the original collection itself? This is somewhat confusing to me since `List<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is an interface and `List<T>` does not inherit it, it **implements** it. That's a huge difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conceptually, this may be because `IEnumerable` is used when you want to represent an immutable collection of items. That is, you only want to read the items in the list, but not add/insert/delete or otherwise change the collection. In this view of the data, returning a new `IEnumerable` in a different order is the expected result. When you use a `List`, you expected to be able to add/insert/delete or otherwise mutate the collection, so a `Reverse` method that changes the order of the original list would be expected in that context.

As others have noted `IEnumerable` is an interface and `List` is a class. `List` implements `IEnumerable`.

So,

```
 IEnumerable<String> names = new List<String>();
 var reversedNames = names.Reverse();
```

gets you a second list, reversed. 
Whereas,

```
 List<String> names = new List<String>();
 names.Reverse();
```

Reverses your original list. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 11):

Because they're two different methods.

[`List<T>.Reverse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an instance method on `List<T>`.  This modifies the List in place.

[`Enumerable.Reverse<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358497%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`.  This creates a new sequence that enumerates the source sequence in reverse order.

You can use the latter on a `List<T>` by calling as a static method:

```
var list = new List<string>{"1","2"};
var reversed = Enumerable.Reverse(list)
```

Or by casting to `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<string> list = new List<string>{"1","2"};
var reversed = list.Reverse();
```

In both these cases, `list` remains unchanged and `reversed` when enumerated returns `{"2","1"}`.

Comment: I've added an Extension method 'Reverse**d**' that just wraps Ienumerable.Reverse - quite often you want immutability, and now you can just call it without any casting or other boilerplate code.

Answer (score 3):

`Reverse` on `IEnumerable<T>` is part of Linq and is added as extension method (`Enumerable.Reverse<T>`). It was added after `Reverse` was implemented for `List<T>`.

`IEnumerable<T>` isn't a collection of objects either. It just tells the consumer how to get at those items.

Comment: Looks like this answer is the only one that explains the *why*: *"It was added after `Reverse` was implemented for `List<T>`"*

Answer (score 0):

These are different methods, remember. Essentially different, with nothing common but a name.

`void List.Reverse` is a method of List instance only, and it does in place reversal of list or part of it.

`IEnumerable Enumerable.Reverse` is an extension method (btw `IList` also has it!) creates a new enumerable with order reversed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `IEnumerable<T>.Reverse()` It's `Enumerable.Reverse<T>(this IEnumerable<T>)` and it's extension method from Linq applied to all `IEnumerable<>`.

Now that we've established when they come from, it's easy to understand why they are so different. Linq adds methods for creating "processing streams", and it's achieved by creating new instance every time.

`List<T>.Reverse()` is a method of `List` and like all it's methods (eg `Add`) directly modifies the instance.

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable<T>` has an underlying implementation, which could be `List<T>`, `Hashtable<T>` or something else that implements IEnumerable.

`List<T>` itself *is* the implementation, so you can directly modify that instance.

And as everyone else has mentioned, one is an extension method and part of Linq, and one is implemented directly on the type.